# How to transfer specific column data to table1 to table2 on Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created two table project1, project2 on Google BigQuery and I'd like to transfer only one column data,"cv_date" from project1 to project2 which has different scheme form project1. I have already found some articles about copying a whole table to another table in same scheme but I couldn't find the solution about my problem .
Could anyone tell me ??

[project1]
node_id|folder_id|user_name|user_age|cv_date←I want to transfer this column data
[project2]
client_id|client_name|products_price|cv_date

Comment: How's the logic beneath the "transfer"? Is it a join? Or simply a concatenation of the column, so the two tables have the same number of records?

Comment: Sorry for  late response  . I mean this transfer as a moving data to another project's table, it's like copy . I just want cv_date to project2 .Those two table hasn't same records and each table is  in different project .

Comment: I could move the data that I want  from project1 to project2 with traditional SQL. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could move the data that I want from project1 to project2 with traditional SQL as follow.

```html
insert into test_project.project2(cv_date)
select cv_date 
from test-266110.conversion_log.project2
```